# Emulators for Windows 10 Mobile not available to install

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-cordova, windows-phone-emulator

I'm using `Visual Studio 2015 Professional Update 3` and I'm trying to modify VS and add `Emulators for Windows 10 Mobile`.

Unfortunately, it doesn't list `Emulators for Windows 10 Mobile` as an option.

[image]

[image]

Note: I am using remote desktop to connect to the computer.  Hype-v is enabled.

Comment: To narrow down the question, I want to ask a few questions:1. Are you running on a Virtual Machine? 2. Is your current windows user administrator to that remote machine? 3. Could you please give some information of the OS version of your remote machine and maybe share the link,where you download the update3?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT
Running on a PC.  Not virtual machine.
I am not an administrator, but I can elevate permissions to administrator when I run VS2015.  I have used this approach on my local machine and I'm able to see the features and can add.
OS = Windows 10 Enterprise; 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.  I verified the following was setup:

- `Intel VT` was enabled on the BIOS
- Verified `Hyper-V` feature was not enabled on Windows 10
- Manually installed the `intelhaxm-android.exe`
  More Info: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Once those were installed/enabled and/or verified, I was able to modify VS2015 and see the features.